# How can I get subclasses to return their own type?

Tags: java, generics

Here we have multiple custom query-DSLs that use related grammar. I am creating to create an `AbstractBuilder` so that all the commonality can be written in one place. The problem is that is causes issues with method-chaining. When I try to chain from a method in to `AbstractBuilder` so a subclass, it doesn't work without casting.

With these classes:

```
class AbstractBuilder{
    protected final StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();

    AbstractBuilder addValue( String name, String value ){
        bldr.append( name ).append( '=' ).append( value )append( ',' );
        return this;
    }

    String toString(){
        return bldr.toString();
    }
}

class IntBuilder extends AbstractBuilder{

    IntBuilder addValue( String name, int value ){
        bldr.append( name ).append( '=' ).append( value )append( ',' );
        return this;
    }
}
```

This works

```
new IntBuilder().addValue( "age", 12 ).addValue( "name", "Bruce" ).toString();` but `new IntBuilder().addValue( "name", "Bruce" ).addValue( "age", 12 ).toString();
```

doesn't unless you make an ugly cast like:

```
((IntBuilder) (new IntBuilder().addValue( "name", "Bruce" ))).addValue( "age", 12 ).toString();
```

Now I guess I could override each methods and implement them with calls to their parents (via `super.addValue( name, value );`), but that is really ugly.

How else can I get every method to return the current class and not the class on which it was defined?

Comment: You have a much bigger problem there: You have two StringBuilders instead of one in the base class with protected access rights. Even your simple example doesn't return the right result :)

Comment: I created smaple code from scratch, so I never ran it but good catch! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve this using generics.

```
class BaseBuilder<B extends BaseBuilder>{
    protected final StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
    private Class<B> builderImplementationClass;

    protected BaseBuilder( Class<B> builderImpl ){
        builderImplementationClass = builderImpl;

        if( this.getClass() != builderImpl )
            throw new IllegalStateException( "Should match." );
    }

    B addValue( String name, String value ){
        bldr.append( name ).append( '=' ).append( value )append( ',' );
        return builderImplementationClass.cast( this );
    }

    String toString(){
        return bldr.toString();
    }
}

class IntBuilder extends AbstractBuilder<IntBuilder>{

    public IntBuilder(){
        super( IntBuilder.class );
    }

    IntBuilder addValue( String name, int value ){
        bldr.append( name ).append( '=' ).append( value )append( ',' );
        return this;
    }
}
```

Basically you make all your methods return a value of type `B` and make sure that `B` is set to your current Implementation

Comment: The really interesting problem here actually is how you have to define the classes so that you can actually extend from `IntBuilder` too - don't think it's actually possible without having to put some burden on the calling code (by making it have to specify the generic bound itself) or refactoring the IntBuilder to an abstract class.

Comment: I think it is doable if you add a `protected` constructor that'll chain and you'll need to make `IntBuilder` generic as well.

Comment: Yeah the problem is if you make `IntBuilder` generic, you either make it an abstract class and have a definite `IntBuilder2` class inherit from it (which removes the generic), or users of the class have to call it with `new IntBuilder<IntBuilder>()`. The first one assumes we can make such a big change later on and the later one is just horrible. That's the two things I came up with too - probably best to use Factories in such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

ArtB's solution is good, but you can make it a bit simpler with the following:

```
private static class AbstractBuilder <T extends AbstractBuilder<T>> {
    protected StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();

    public T addValue( String name, String value ){
        bldr.append( name ).append( '=' ).append( value ).append(',');
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T result = (T)this;
        return result;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return bldr.toString();
    }
}

private static class IntBuilder extends AbstractBuilder<IntBuilder> {

    public IntBuilder addValue( String name, int value ){
        bldr.append( name ).append( '=' ).append( value ).append(',');
        return this;
    }
}
```

Note I also fixed the bug with the two private StringBuilder variables, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Sure, but when compiling you won't you get an `unchecked conversion` warning? That is the downside of casting generically vs using the `cast()` method on a class.

Comment: Sure, but the cast does exactly the same, except that the compiler doesn't give any warnings. You can throw in a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in the baseclass, which is a good idea though.

Comment: @Voo: `.cast()` *doesn't* do exactly the same, because it checks it at runtime, and throws an exception if the type doesn't match, so it's not an unchecked cast.

Comment: The unchecked cast here is unsafe (i.e. `this` is not necessarily an instance of `T`).

Comment: @newacct If `this` isn't a T, there will be a runtime exception here just as much as in the `cast()` version. Only difference is what kind of exception, but clearly that could be tweaked.

Comment: @Voo: Yes, and they're both unsafe, because it's not possible to have a type variable that represent the type of `this` in Java.